# Order query output according to 'is in table/ is not in table'

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following Database Design:

[Database Design](https://pl.vc/155un)

I want to get all Information from table 'info' where the id IS NOT in table 'archived'. To do so I wrote:

```
SELECT *
  FROM traffic_info i
LEFT JOIN
  traffic_info_archived a ON (i.info_id = a.info_id)
WHERE
  i.branch_id = 4 AND i.user_id = 7 a.info_id IS NULL ORDER BY i.info_date_from ASC
```

This works as expected.
The next challenge is to only show information that are also included in the 'published' table. To get this done I have expanded my previous query to :

```
SELECT *
  FROM traffic_info i
LEFT JOIN
  traffic_info_archived a ON (i.info_id = a.info_id)
RIGHT JOIN 
  traffic_info_publised p ON (i.info_id = p.info_id)
WHERE
  i.branch_id = 4 AND a.info_id AND i.user_id = 7 IS NULL ORDER BY i.info_date_from ASC
```

This does also work as expected.
The final challenge is to Order this result according to table 'read'. Information´s id that are NOT in table 'read' should be ordered ASC. But even if its id does not appear in table 'read' they should not be excluded from the query output. BUT the primary ORDER should be

```
i.info_date_from ASC
```

I hope this is understandable, my English is not the best :) If not, please comment and I will do my best to make it understandable. Hope some can help!

I´ve tried to create a SQLFiddle, but I wasn´t able to create a runnable example, sorry for that.

UPADTE:

Using the approach from @Dylan Su

```
SELECT *
 FROM traffic_info i
LEFT JOIN
  traffic_info_archived a ON (i.info_id = a.info_id)
INNER JOIN 
  traffic_info_publised p ON (i.info_id = p.info_id)
WHERE
   i.branch_id = 4 AND a.info_id AND i.user_id = 7 IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM read WHERE i.info_id = read.info_id)
        THEN i.info_date_from END ASC;
```

the goal is nearer then it ever was :)
[Sample Data output](https://pl.vc/30c4j)

Both entries marked with a red "X" are in table read. Therefore id 3 should be last the, in the middle 1 and 2 at the top.

So the last thing to archive is to do the correct order of table read. I´ve tried sth like:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM traffic_info_read WHERE i.info_id = traffic_info_read.info_id ORDER BY traffic_info_read.info_id DESC)
```

But that didn´t had any influnce.

Comment: pls explain the expected order. `Information´s id that are NOT in table 'read' should be ordered ASC. But even if its id does not appear in table 'read' they should not be excluded from the query output. BUT the primary ORDER should be` This is really confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM traffic_info i
LEFT JOIN
  traffic_info_archived a ON (i.info_id = a.info_id)
INNER JOIN 
  traffic_info_publised p ON (i.info_id = p.info_id)
WHERE
  i.branch_id = 4 AND a.info_id AND i.user_id = 7 IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM read WHERE i.info_id = read.info_id) ASC, 
    i.info_date_from ASC;
```

Comment: Here we go sir. Now I got what I expected! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of @Dylan Su is absolutely correct and I won´t unmark it as accepted.
However, based on the Information I gained from the conversation I have created another solution, that doesn´t make use of sub query.

I heard that using just JOIN´s will result in better performance, I don´t know if it´s correct and I don´t have that much test data currently to find out, but here is the solution using no sub query.

```
SELECT *
 FROM traffic_info i
LEFT JOIN
 traffic_info_archived a ON (i.info_id = a.info_id)
INNER JOIN
 traffic_info_published p ON (i.info_id = p.info_id)
LEFT JOIN 
 traffic_info_read r ON (i.info_id = r.info_id)
WHERE
  i.branch_id = 4 AND a.info_id IS NULL ORDER BY r.info_id IS NULL DESC,    i.info_date_from ASC
;
```